# How to use different web.xml file for different running environments with maven

Tags: maven, web.xml

I have a JSF2 project that is deployed in a JBoss 7 server. When running the application in my own computer (during development and testing), I use a version of `web.xml` file with certain content, but when I have to deploy the same application in the production server, I have to use different settings in the same `web.xml` file.

Nowadays I have to comment some parts and uncomment others in each situation, what seems to be a very poor "solution" for my situation.

How could I have different `web.xml` files or contents that will be used in different deploy conditions?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jenkins to deploy your application. That has plugins named Config File Provider that allow you to configure files based on your requirement. So in that way you can use second version of web.xml and jenkin will deploy application with your new web.xml

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but making a decision on what product to use to deploy goes beyond my authority. Ins't there a way that uses only Maven?

Comment: Yes you can also use  maven-war-plugin of maven and configure profiles and its related files.